# How to print out result with Intellij scala console in Mac

Tags: macos, scala, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using IntelliJ to develop my Scala program. I run Scala console to interactively execute some code, but I fail to print the result. The official document says <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> will help, but I have tried that and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It is: **command + enter** in Mac.

BTW, in Windows, open 'settings', search 'keymap'.

And configure the 'Scala' -> '**Execute  Console Statement**', as follows.

[image]

Comment: This isn't doing it for me. When I Cmd+Enter on OS X (which is the current shortcut) it just inserts a line below the current line, like Cmd+Enter usually does. Even if I add a key mapping for something unused like Ctrl+Alt+Cmd+L, nothing happens when I press it in the Scala console.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in version 14.1 due a bug. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8521

Use sbt console as a workaround.